# Why is my property always wrong, even though it gets changed and is a dependency?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have these properties declared in my app:

```
  const [lockfileData, setLockFileData] = useState({});
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<RiotWSProtocol>(null);
  const [api, setApi] = useState<LoLAPI>(null);

  const [champions, setChampions] = useState<Champion[]>([]);
  const [summoner, setSummoner] = useState<Summoner>(null);

  const [autoAcceptQueue, setAutoAccept] = useState(true);
  const [instalockEnabled, setEnableInstalock] = useState(true);
  const [selectedChampion, setSelectedChampion] = useState<Champion>(null);
  const [callRoleEnabled, setCallRoleEnabled] = useState(true);
  const [selectedRole, setSelectedRole] = useState<Role>('Mid');
```

I have an event handler in my `useEffect` hook, and inside that it handles more events:

```
  const onJsonApiEvent = useCallback(
    (message: any) => {
      //console.log(message);
      if (
        message.uri === '/lol-matchmaking/v1/ready-check' &&
        autoAcceptQueue
      ) {
        if (
          message.data?.state === 'InProgress' &&
          message.data?.playerResponse !== 'Accepted'
        ) {
          api.acceptQueue();
        }
      } else if (
        message.uri === '/lol-champ-select/v1/session' &&
        message.eventType === 'Update'
      ) {
        console.log('enabled?', instalockEnabled)
        if (instalockEnabled) {
          const myCellId = message.data.localPlayerCellId as number;
          const myAction = (message.data.actions[0] as any[]).find(
            (x) => x.actorCellId === myCellId
          );
          if (
            !myAction.completed &&
            myAction.isInProgress &&
            myAction.type === 'pick'
          ) {
            api.pickAndLockChampion(1, myAction.id);
          }
          console.log('myAction', myAction);
        }
      }
    },
    [api, autoAcceptQueue, instalockEnabled]
  );

  const onSocketOpen = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('socket', socket);
    if (socket) {
      socket.subscribe('OnJsonApiEvent', onJsonApiEvent);
    }
  }, [onJsonApiEvent, socket]);

  const onConnect = useCallback((data: LCUCredentials) => {
    setLockFileData(data);
    const lolApi = new LoLAPI(data);
    setApi(lolApi);
    lolApi.getOwnedChampions().then((champs) => {
      setSelectedChampion(champs[0]);
      setChampions(champs);
    });
    lolApi.getCurrentSummoner().then((summoner) => {
      setSummoner(summoner);
    });
    const wss = new RiotWSProtocol(
      `wss://${data.username}:${data.password}@${data.host}:${data.port}`
    );
    setSocket(wss);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on('open', onSocketOpen);
    }
    connector.on('connect', onConnect);
    connector.start();
    return () => {
      connector.stop();
    };
  }, [onConnect, onSocketOpen, socket]);
```

The dependencies appear to be correct, so it should be using the up to date values in each handler.

However, inside the `onJsonApiEvent` handler, properties such as `instalockEnabled` are always the default value.

I am updating the value of `instalockEnabled` in a component on my page:

```
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                checked={instalockEnabled}
                name="instalockEnabled"
                color="primary"
                onChange={handleInstalockEnableChange}
              />
            }
            label="Enabled"
          />
```

And its handler looks like this:

```
  const handleInstalockEnableChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setEnableInstalock(e.target.checked);
  };
```

How come this is happening when it is a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

The janky solution I've come up with for now is to have a separate variable that is `useRef` and update that at the same time as updating the state, therefore it persists:

```
  const [instalockEnabled, setEnableInstalock] = useState(true);
  const instalockEnabledRef = useRef(instalockEnabled);

  const handleInstalockEnableChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setEnableInstalock(e.target.checked);
    instalockEnabledRef.current = e.target.checked;
  };
```

And then just use `instalockEnabledRef.current` inside of the event handlers where it needs to know the current value.